# Dynamically Changing scrollTime

Tags: fullcalendar

As the view changes, I'd like to update the scrollTime. For example: if I have events that start at 10AM one day, but 6PM the next, I'd like to have that first event in focus. I've tried:

```
viewRender: function(view, el) {
  view.options.scrollTime = someNewTime;
}
```

It doesn't update the scroll position. Interestingly if I change the view a few more times, eventually it does seem to change the scroll position.

Do I need to force a re-render or is there another way?

Here's a codepen showing the behavior.
https://codepen.io/noynek/pen/EvvVLW

Comment: can you make a StackSnippet or JSFiddle which demonstrates the issue, please?

Comment: I've added a codepen showing the behavior. Change the view once and there's no effect. Change it twice and the scrollPosition is correctly set to 8AM.

Comment: From https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/viewRender/, "This callback will trigger after the view has been fully rendered". Since you set the scrollTime option during that callback, then the first time it runs it cannot have any effect because the view has already been rendered prior to the callback running. It will only get used the next time a view is rendered.

Comment: The callback timing issue makes sense, but I'm still wondering is there's a solution. An ugly one seems like setting scrollTime on nav link click events.

Comment: It might not be completely ugly, since there are callbacks to handle those clicks that you can already tap into: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/navLinkDayClick/ and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/navLinkWeekClick/. And for the left/right /view name buttons normally at the top, you could replace them with custom buttons: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/customButtons/ . Worth trying at any rate. I can't think of another way at the moment.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll look into these options. Glad to be sure I'm not missing the "correct" way. Thanks